# Jssor slider implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, jssor

I've been using jssor slider on a few pages and it's been working fine, but now I have some problems..
The way I actually want it is to be hidden at first and then show with another script. This I got covered but the slider won't load..
For the sake of debugging, I have skipped this hidden thingy but I still can't solve this.

I tried to clean this up the best I could...

I have jquery 2.1.3 and newest bootstrap at the beginning of the document

The whole "proper" site is available at http://mirojohansson.com/index_new.html
and the slider should show on land

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
            var options = {
                $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
                $SlideDuration: 800,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                    $Scale: false,                                  //Scales bullets navigator or not while slider scale
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };

            //Make the element 'slider1_container' visible before initialize jssor slider.
            $("#slider1_container").css("display", "block");
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                if (bodyWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });

/* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 21 css */
                /*
                .jssorb21 div           (normal)
                .jssorb21 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
                .jssorb21 .av           (active)
                .jssorb21 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
                .jssorb21 .dn           (mousedown)
                */
                .jssorb21 div, .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av {
                    background: url(img/b21.png) no-repeat;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                .jssorb21 div {
                    background-position: -5px -5px;
                }

                    .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av:hover {
                        background-position: -35px -5px;
                    }

                .jssorb21 .av {
                    background-position: -65px -5px;
                }

                .jssorb21 .dn, .jssorb21 .dn:hover {
                    background-position: -95px -5px;
                }    

/* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 21 css */
                /*
                .jssora21l              (normal)
                .jssora21r              (normal)
                .jssora21l:hover        (normal mouseover)
                .jssora21r:hover        (normal mouseover)
                .jssora21ldn            (mousedown)
                .jssora21rdn            (mousedown)
                */
                .jssora21l, .jssora21r, .jssora21ldn, .jssora21rdn {
                    position: absolute;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display: block;
                    background: url(img/a21.png) center center no-repeat;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }

                .jssora21l {
                    background-position: -3px -33px;
                }

                .jssora21r {
                    background-position: -63px -33px;
                }

                .jssora21l:hover {
                    background-position: -123px -33px;
                }

                .jssora21r:hover {
                    background-position: -183px -33px;
                }

                .jssora21ldn {
                    background-position: -243px -33px;
                }

                .jssora21rdn {
                    background-position: -303px -33px;
                }

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="illu" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw">
            <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->
        <!-- ================================================== -->
        <div id="slider1_container" style="display: none; position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
        top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 700px; overflow: hidden;">


            <!-- Slides Container -->
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 700px; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="background: blue">
                </div>
                <div style="background: blue" />
                </div>
                <div style="background: red">
                </div>
                <div style="background: green">
                </div>
            </div>



            <!-- bullet navigator container -->
            <div u="navigator" class="jssorb21" style="position: absolute; bottom: 26px; left: 6px;">
                <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
                <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 19px; HEIGHT: 19px; text-align:center; line-height:19px; color:White; font-size:12px;"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Arrow Left -->
            <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora21l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
            </span>
            <!-- Arrow Right -->
            <span u="arrowright" class="jssora21r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
            </span>
            <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
            <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Bootstrap Slider</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by trying again from scratch. Can't say what the problem was but I'm glad it got fixed.